# C++ class and emacs editor

Tags: c++, emacs

Emacs in C++ mode formats the code like this, how to make that put also a tab after public.

```
namespace Z
{
  class Z
  {
    public:
    Z();
```

Comment: When putting code in SO questions, please indent it with four spaces to format it correctly.

Comment: Normally, ctrl-Q-tab is sufficient to put a tab anywhere, but I think you'll find it removes trailing whitespace on save so there's actually no point.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what Umut wants is for the line `Z();` to be shifted right another indent level.

Answer (score 0):

some quick searching leads me to think this won't be too easy.

you could try the workaround described [here](http://osdir.com/ml/help-gnu-emacs-gnu/2009-09/msg00591.html)

Comment: EMACS is the most configurable editors (sorry I mean development environment (sorry I mean easter egg play ground)) ever built I would be surprised if somebody had not done the appropriate configuration.

Comment: At least as of the date of the email Bwmat linked to, it sounds like the major mode could not do this without a nontrivial chunk of extra Lisp.  I'm surprised too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand it.

But here is a page on cofiguring indentation for C/C++ like languages on EMACS
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC

Comment: No amount of configuration to indentation is going to put a tab after public.

Comment: CC mode does some strange indention in source files and in header files and it is completely different in the header and source, or I am mistaken at some points, still...

Comment: @Noah, so you say it is not possible to make indention for the public interface in emacs, I am coming to the conclusion(maybe a bit faster than expected) that vi rocks...